# PyCUDA kernel timing errors

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, pycuda

Simple enough

```
start=cuda.Event()
func(args,block=blockdims)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(d,h)
end=cuda.Event()

dur=start.time_till(end)
print dur
```

But I'm getting this error

```
File "gpu.py", line 161, in gpu_test
    dur=start.time_till(end)
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuEventElapsedTime failed: invalid handle
```

This is as far as I can tell from the [docs](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.Event) the correct usage. Anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SimpleSpeedTest.py](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/SimpleSpeedTest):

```
start=cuda.Event()
end=cuda.Event()

start.record() # start timing
func(args,block=blockdims)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(d,h)
end.record() # end timing
# calculate the run length
end.synchronize()
millis = start.time_till(end)
print millis
```

Comment: This is how is should be done. A pair of record events need to be inserted in the stream around the action being timed. Synchronizing the stream will make the host wait until the stream is idle, which also ensures both record events have been processed by the driver.